# Connecting to other database in WordPress - 'orderby' => 'meta_value' does not work

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to retrieve old Events from another WordPress instance and sort them by a meta value "date_from" (= start date) which is stored by ACF as yyyymmdd. The query works well except for the ORDER-part. I tried to order by another meta value, which does not work either. However, ordering does work with the same code in another project when I query the original WordPress database. Any ideas? Thanks! Here is my code:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
$wpdb->set_prefix('zem_');
$wpdb->show_errors();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_key' => 'date_from',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',      // order by start date (does not work! also meta_value_num)
    'order' => 'ASC',

    'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => 'date_from',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<',       // get old events (works!)
        ),

    ),
    
);
```

Comment: Found the solution now by myself: The problem was the plugin "Post Types Order". This seems to override all custom order instructions! I had to deactivate it and now ordering works like it should, according to the code above.